# I have a Quadra-fire topaz direct vent gas fireplace, what type thermostat is needed

Tags: thermostat, gas, fireplace

I'm looking to run a thermostat to my gas fireplace, it's a millivolt system, how do I wire the thermostat correctly

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Have you tried looking at the fireplace's manual? And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: What make and model of thermostat are you wanting to use, or are you still trying to select it?